# AlertDialog crashes on one array of string and not on the other - they appear same?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I dynamically build array of strings for AlertDialog in Android device.
I create array 1 of strings like this :

```
 final int       SAMPLERATES_NUM = 9;
 String[]       SampleRates_Str = new String[SAMPLERATES_NUM];

 SampleRates_Str[ValidSampleRate_Index] = Integer.toString(SampRate);
```

Now I create array2 of strings simply by :

```
 String[] SampleRates_Str1 = {"48000", "44100", "32000", "22050", "16000", "11025", "8000", "4000"};
```

Now I call AlertDialog and present those two arrays (one at the time). System crashes on SampleRates_Str but works on SampleRates_Str1 - but when I inspect them in ADK, they appear with exactly the same content (at least to me)...

```
public void createListAlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Pick a Sampling Rate");
     String[] SampleRates_Str1 = {"48000", "44100", "32000", "22050", "16000", "11025", "8000", "4000"};
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(SampleRates_Str1, SampleRates_Index,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    SampleRates_Index = item;
                }
            });

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { // Add the OK button
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    PickFsDone = true;
                }
            }
     );

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Why the difference ?

First few lines in crash log :

```
10-11 04:56:36.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3144): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-11 04:56:36.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3144): Process: processing.test.soundanalyzer, PID: 3144
10-11 04:56:36.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3144): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference 
10-11 04:56:36.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3144): at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
```

Thanks in advance,
regards Rob.

Answer (score 0):

The array1 has only 8 variables. So

```
final int       SAMPLERATES_NUM = 9;
```

should be

```
final int       SAMPLERATES_NUM = 8;
```

Or at least one of variables is not initialized to be remained null.

Comment: Same situation even if I set SampleRates_Str1 to 9 strings.... I really wonder what could make the difference. In Watch window they both look the same...

Comment: First few lines in crash log :<br>10-11 04:56:36.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3144): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-11 04:56:36.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3144): Process: processing.test.soundanalyzer, PID: 3144
10-11 04:56:36.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3144): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
10-11 04:56:36.746: E/AndroidRuntime(3144):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)

Comment: Apparently you failed initializing about array1. At least one of array1's variables can be null.

Comment: You're right... One  element was null, since I didn't initialize all of them. I've solved it with arraylist, that is dinamically created, and then changed to array when used in AlertDialog. Now it works...